# select date column on mysql is giving only 0000-00-00 results

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query

```
select date_of_birth from clients
where date_of_birth BETWEEN '1988-11-09' and '1968-11-09';
```

but only gives 0000-00-00 results,what is wrong?

Comment: i cannot replicate this result: `SELECT '0000-00-00' BETWEEN '1988-11-09' AND '1968-11-09' x;  x -> 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smaller value should be on the left side and bigger on the right side in case of [`BETWEEN .. AND ..`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

```
select date_of_birth from clients
where date_of_birth BETWEEN '1968-11-09' and '1988-11-09';
```